# MVC Use a PartialView in multiple views with different models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This question has been answered [MVC PartialView in multiple Views with different models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001456/mvc-partialview-in-multiple-views-with-different-models) but I am not getting the syntax right. I would like to get the Model to a ViewData in controller and pass it to a view in code below.

**_PartialIndex.cshtml**:

```
@*@model Models.Org.OrgListViewModel*@

@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Organization";
}

@section styles {

}

<div class="col-sm-11">
    @if (Model.OrganizationList == null || Model.OrganizationList.Count == 0)
        {
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h6 class="text-bold text-danger text-center"> No records</h6>
            </div>
        }
    <div class="panel panel-default card-view">
     @if (Model.OrganizationList.TotalItemCount > 0)
        {
            //Bind data to datatable
        }
        else
        {
            <h6 class="text-center text-danger">No Data Retrieved!</h6>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using Models.Leads
@model LeadsListViewModel

@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Leads";
}

@section styles {

    enter code here

}

<div class="row">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialIndex",ViewBag.Model) //ViewBag.Model Not working
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchText, int page = 1)
{

    var model = await repo.GetLeadsAsync(searchText, page);

   // ViewData["Model"] = "LeadsListViewModel"; //Cant get the syntax right

    return View(new LeadsListViewModel() { LeadsList = model, TotalItemCount = model.TotalItemCount });
}
```

Comment: Make Them inhert from the Same parent ModelClass then do some downcasting At runtime. basic object oriented

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like that. You can use partial view with same model in different main views. The logical way to implement this is by using Generic. But we can't use it in mvc partial view